# Design of SIMD-implemented cipher

Tags: block-cipher, stream-cipher, s-boxes, spn

Design of efficient of block ciphers needs consideration of many factors such as register size. i found that some ciphers can be SIMD implemented such as [TWINE](https://www.nec.com/en/global/rd/tg/code/symenc/pdf/twine_LC11.pdf) , [SM4](https://github.com/mjosaarinen/sm4ni) , [chacha20](https://github.com/sneves/chacha-avx2/blob/master/chacha-avx2.c) ,[SPIX](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Lightweight-Cryptography/documents/round-1/spec-doc/spix-spec.pdf) ,and others.

1. What components in block (Feistel and SPN) and stream ciphers are tricky to be implemented in vectorizations?
2. Does the Sbox size (4 bit or 8 bit) or the F-function structure (such as simon-like Sbox in SPIX or SP/SPS such as in Clefia or piccolo) matter ?
3. Does  the  branch number in Feistel Type (2,4,6,8 ..) have related in number of blocks to be packed for vectorization?